# Mapping key/value with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dictionary

Is there any way to map keys and values ​​in an array using Javascript? In my opinion, it is something similar to jQuery [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), but instead of mapping only the value, also "maps" the keys.

Suppose I have the following array:

```
var names = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
```

And I like to use a function called `numberToName()` that I created and generate another array from this, and the result should be something like this:

```
var names = { "one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3, "four": 4, "five": 5 };
```

Currently I use the following method:

```
var names = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
    names_tmp = {},
    names_i = 0,
    names_len = names.length;

for(; names_i < names_len; names_i++) {
    names_tmp[numberToName(names[names_i])] = names[names_i];
}
```

The question is: is there any way (preferably native) to improve this method? I could even use jQuery without problems. Perhaps a function similar to this:

```
var names = jQuery.mapKeys([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function(k, v) {
    return { key: numberToName(v), value: v };
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `reduce`:

```
var names = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(function(obj, k) {
     return obj[numberToName(k)] = k, obj;
}, {});
```

`return obj[numberToName(k)] = k, obj` is a shorthand (and admittedly less readable) way to write  assignment + return:

```
     obj[numberToName(k)] = k;
     return obj;
```

A simple `forEach` will do the job too:

```
names = {};
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach(function(k) {
   names[numberToName(k)] = k
})
```

You can also use jquery's `$.each` in the same way if you want.

Comment: umm, no he's not. that's a bass-ackwards way of pretending reduce is map or foreach...

Comment: @dandavis: I see you understood the question and edited your post. I think `forEach` is better than `map` here though (if you dislike reduce for some reason).

Comment: kill the closure and i'll remove my answer.

Comment: @dandavis: let the OP decide.

Comment: I think that .reduce() works better for me, because I need return the value as array directly to var. forEach will not do that. Right?

Comment: @DavidRodrigues: this is correct. With `forEach` you have to pre-initialize the accumulator, with `reduce` you pass it as a second argument.

Comment: Please, can you explain the line 2 of .reduce method? `k, obj`?

Comment: @DavidRodrigues: added an explanation to the post.

Comment: I think that .reduce() method is a bit faster. http://jsperf.com/mapping-key-value Thanks!

Comment: you can return two things in a foreach, just like with the reduce. i typically "return this[a]=1, this;" using it externally like arr.map(fn,{})[0], but that's just force of habit. since **this** is the same thing each return, it doesn't waste RAM (in my measurements) to return an array full of this. there should be no real performance diff between forEach, map, and reduce because the mechanics are 90% the same. reduce and forEach are both great options, so 21st centuury compared to for...

Answer (score 1):

sure is, (as of IE9):

```
var nums={};
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach(function(v, i) {
    this[numberToName(v)]=v; 
}, nums);

nums;
```

EDIT: added an index to make it easier to tell what's going on.

EDIT: made it perfect by using forEach, which even though it's not as close to $'s .map(), does run about 3% faster than [].map. (thanks to thg435 for the tip!)